# React Redux not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using the React Hooks implementation of React-Redux. Below is the flow of my code. For some reason any values that I pass in my `dispatch(fuction(value))` is not detected in my reducer. I can't figure it out.

src/components/categories/selectCategory.tsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
    import {setCategory} from '../../store/actions';

    const selectCategory = (name: string) => {
        dispatch(setCategory(name)); // ex: name = 'algebra'
    };
```

store/actions/index.ts

```js
export const setCategory = (name) => ({
    type: 'SET_CATEGORY',
    name: name
});
```

store/reducers/index.ts

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import category from './category';

const app = combineReducers({
    category
});

export default app;
```

store/reducers/category.ts

```js
const initialState = {
    name: 'calculus'
};

const category = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_CATEGORY':
            return {name: state.name}; // outputs 'calculus'
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default category;
```

I'm sure there is some small detail I am missing.

Comment: return action.name in your reducer instead

Comment: @ducmai that works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was fixed by returning the `action.name` property instead of `state.name`.

store/reducers/category.ts

```js
const initialState = {
    name: 'calculus'
};

const category = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_CATEGORY':
            return {name: action.name};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default category;
```